# how to delay animate move jlabel java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I want to move so some label from x to y! But i dont know how to delay it!

i was tried Thread.sleep but it not work, someone say it cause by blocking EDT , but because of my bad english, i cant learning myself on internet! Please help me a example! Thanks!

Here my code:

```
    public void jump(JLabel x, int y){
         x.setLocation(x.getX()+y, 310);
 }
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jump(frog3,100);
        //i want to delay each jump about 1 second! please give me some example! 
        jump(fr0g3,-200);

        jump(fr0g2,-100);

        jump(frog3,200);

        jump(frog2,200);

        jump(frog1,100);        

        jump(fr0g3,-200);

        jump(fr0g2,-200);

        jump(fr0g1,-200);

        jump(frog3,100);

        jump(frog2,200);

        jump(frog1,200);

        jump(fr0g2,-100);

        jump(fr0g1,-200);

        jump(frog1,100);

    }
```

thank for reading!

Comment: Use [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: :'( this is my problem :v i cant read english :v i'm tried timer too but it's not work

Comment: [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) - We're going to help telling you the same thing - the simplest solution is a Swing `Timer` - it's just a pudo loop which has a delayed automatically applied

Comment: tks for your helps ! ==' but i dont relize it !

Comment: Quit reposting questions. This is your 3rd question on the same topic. You have been given plenty of help but have not made an effort to listen to the suggestions given. `i'm tried timer too but it's not work` - you have never posted code showing what you tried so how can we help. You have also been given other solutions that don't involve using a Timer. You simply use another Thread and then your sleep() logic will work. So pay attention to the suggestion and don't keep wasting people time.

Answer (score 3):

> i cant read english

So forgive me if this answer is light on text

At the very simplest...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel("Testing");
        private int delta = 4;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(null);
            label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
            add(label);
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int x = label.getX() + delta;
                    if (x + label.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        x = getWidth() - label.getWidth();
                        delta *= -1;
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        x = 0;
                        delta *= -1;
                    }
                    int y = (getHeight() - label.getHeight()) / 2;
                    label.setLocation(x, y);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

I don't like `null` layouts, I don't recommend `null` layouts, but seen as this is a school assignment and the only other viable solution is to use custom painting, I appreciate why might choose this direction, although a custom painting solution would generally be simpler.

Comment: sr but my jump solution isn't a loop ! I can use timer?

Comment: @KaiLoveMika yes you can. You simply need to pack all your stuff in a `List`.

Comment: @KaiLoveMika Yes it is, you have a value which changes over time